# react native error when install native-base or any

Tags: android, node.js, git, react-native, native-base

I'm a React Native beginner. I'm having an issue that after I create a project by command react-native init myapp and it is success but when I install native-base
by command `npm install native-base --save`  that has error as following:

> npm ERR! code ENOGIT npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed using git. npm ERR! Please check if you have git
>
> installed and in your PATH.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>
> C:\Users\myPC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-09-27T09_38_57_379Z-debug.log

I have checked and search google but I cannot find solution to fix it.
I also have installed Git

Help me to fix this. Thanks

Comment: What is the output if you type `which git` in your terminal?

Comment: are you on windows?